# Python Random Number Generator for Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, functional-programming

So I am new to StackOverFlow and I had a quick question about a TicTacToe game I am making in Python.  I have a good part of the game done but I am confused on the computer player's move.  I understand how to make it a random generated number.  I currently have,

```
'board = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]

compTurn = random.randrange(0,9)
board[compTurn] = "O"
printboard(board)`
```

What I need is to make sure that random generated number will not be a space already taken on the board.

So say that I go first in the game and I pick the top left corer or board[0] to place my "X".  How would I make sure the computers random.range will not take a spot that already has a number in it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
random.choice([i for i, e in enumerate(board) if e == " "])
```

This chooses from all the indexes in the board which are empty

Answer (score 0):

For something this small, just track numbers you've used:

```
used = []
r = random.randrange(0,9)
while r in used:
  r = random.randrange(0,9)
used.append(r)
```

That's the simplest way, it works for large numbers as well since probabilisticaly it's constant to respin a number.

Comment: Isn't this a bit inefficient in terms of requiring multiple spins? It could potentially run for an excessively long time, increasing with the number of "used" indexes...

Comment: @SamuelLittley which is why I wouldn't recommend it if you're planning on consuming all results. That being said for n = 10 this isn't a problem. Additionally if you're consuming a small portion of the total choices you could potentially have an infinite runtime but probabilistically you have at worst linear retries. On average you have some constant retries.